# Proving a duality between Ext and Tor for maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over Gorenstein ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, local-cohomology, gorenstein

Let $(R,\mathfrak m, k)$ be a local complete Gorenstein ring of dimension $d$. Let $M,N$ are maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules (i.e. have depth equal to $d$)  that are locally free on the punctured spectrum (i.e. $M_P, N_P$ are free over $R_P$ for every non-maximal prime ideal $P$ of $R$) . Let $E(k)$ be the injective hull of the residue field $k$.

Then, how to prove that

$$\text{Ext}^d_R( \text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*), R)\cong \text{Ext}^{d+i}_R(M,N),\forall i\ge 1$$ ?

Here $(-)^*:=\text{Hom}(-, R)$

My thoughts: Let us write $(-)^{\lor}:=\text{Hom}(-,E(k))$.
Since $M,N$ are locally free on the punctured spectrum, so $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*)$ has finite length for every $i>0$. So $H^0_{\mathfrak m}(\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*))\cong \text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*)$ . So by local duality, we get

$\text{Ext}^d_R( \text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*), R)\cong (H^0_{\mathfrak m}(\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*))^{\lor} \cong ( \text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*))^{\lor}\cong \text{Tor}_i^R(M, H^d_{\mathfrak m}(N)^{\lor})^{\lor} \cong \text{Ext}^i_R(M,  H^d_{\mathfrak m}(N))$

So basically we're trying to prove $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,  H^d_{\mathfrak m}(N))\cong 
\text {Ext}^{d+i}_R(M,N),\forall i\ge 1$.

Also note that for any module $M$, we have a stable isomorphism $syz^2 \text{Tr} M \cong M^*$ , where $syz^2(-)$ denotes second syzygy and $\text{Tr }(-)$ denotes Auslander transpose. So,
$\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N^*)\cong \text{Tor}_{i+2}^R(M, \text {Tr }N)$ .

But I'm unable to simplify things further.

One key point that might be useful is that over Gorenstein local rings, maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules are reflexive and their duals are again maximal Cohen-Macaulay.

Please help.

Comment: You can get rid of that  $N^{*}$ by using local duality and the fact that since $M$ is finitely generated there's an isomorphism $\text{Tor}_{i}(N,\text{Hom}(H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{d}(N),E(k)))\simeq \text{Hom}(\text{Ext}^{i}(M,H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{d}(N)),E(k))$.

Comment: @zeek: thanks for catching that ... I updated it in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proof of Theorem 3.2 in [this survey](http://people.math.sc.edu/kustin/teaching/LocalCohomology/Schenzel-local-cohomology.pdf) of local cohomology by Schenzel it is shown that there is a spectral sequence
$$E_{2}^{i,j}=\text{Ext}_{R}^{i}(M,H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{j}(N))\Rightarrow \text{Ext}_{R}^{n}(M,N)$$
(I do not think the assumptions he makes in the theorem are used to prove the existence of this sequence). Since $N$ is CM this spectral sequence is concentrated in the $j=d$ column so collapses immediately giving isomorphisms
$$Ext_{R}^{i}(M,H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{d}(N))\simeq \text{Ext}_{R}^{i+d}(M,N).$$
This gives the last isomorphism in your post.

Comment: More directly, there is also a Grothendieck spectral sequence $\operatorname{Ext}^p_R(\operatorname{Tor}^R_q(M,N^*),R) \Rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^{p+q}_R(M,N^{**})$ which collapses (taking $q>0$) similarly.